# Given that $f(x)=(2x+1)^3$, find $\int (\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{8h})\,dx$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I thought this was as simple as:
$$
\int \left (\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{8h}\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{8}\int f'(x)\, dx=\frac{f(x)}{8} + C
$$

But the answer is supposed to be:

$$
\left (\frac{2x+1}{2}  \right )^2 + C
$$

How?

Comment: $\frac{f(x)}{8}+C$ because it's indefinite integral. You are almost right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a continuously differentiable function $f$, we have

$$\int f'(x)dx = f(x) + C$$
i.e., you need to write the constant. The indefinite integral is *always* a family of functions, not just a single function. So the correct answer would be $$\frac{f(x)}{8} + C.$$

The answer to the question **you** wrote is certainly not $$\left (\frac{2x+1}{2}  \right )^2 + C$$

Unless you made some typo (highly likely, and I advise you to double check), the answer provided is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$\left (\frac{2x+1}{2}  \right )^2 + C$ is wrong. Correct is $\frac{f(x)}{8}+C.$